# axboot BaseService.java compile error

Tags: javascript, java, user-interface, spring-boot, frameworks

This is a source code of axboot ui framework based on spring-boot.
I download init zip from [this](http://axboot.com/) site.
But, Compiling Error occurs.
So. I browse the source tree in eclipse.
I cannot find Qxxxx Class of BaseService.java.
Anybody, Please let me know where I can find the class bodies.

```
package zoe.youngplussoft.antimalware.domain;

import zoe.youngplussoft.antimalware.domain.code.QCommonCode;
import zoe.youngplussoft.antimalware.domain.file.QCommonFile;
import zoe.youngplussoft.antimalware.domain.program.QProgram;
import zoe.youngplussoft.antimalware.domain.program.menu.QMenu;
import zoe.youngplussoft.antimalware.domain.user.QUser;
import zoe.youngplussoft.antimalware.domain.user.auth.QUserAuth;
import zoe.youngplussoft.antimalware.domain.user.auth.menu.QAuthGroupMenu;
import zoe.youngplussoft.antimalware.domain.user.role.QUserRole;
import com.chequer.axboot.core.domain.base.AXBootBaseService;
import com.chequer.axboot.core.domain.base.AXBootJPAQueryDSLRepository;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class BaseServ`enter code here`ice<T, ID extends Serializable> extends AXBootBaseService<T, ID> {

    protected QUserRole qUserRole = QUserRole.userRole;
    protected QAuthGroupMenu qAuthGroupMenu = QAuthGroupMenu.authGroupMenu;
    protected QCommonCode qCommonCode = QCommonCode.commonCode;
    protected QUser qUser = QUser.user;
    protected QProgram qProgram = QProgram.program;
    protected QUserAuth qUserAuth = QUserAuth.userAuth;
    protected QMenu qMenu = QMenu.menu;
    protected QCommonFile qCommonFile = QCommonFile.commonFile;

    protected AXBootJPAQueryDSLRepository<T, ID> repository;

    public BaseService() {
        super();
    }

    public BaseService(AXBootJPAQueryDSLRepository<T, ID> repository) {
        super(repository);
        this.repository = repository;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Q Classes are auto generated QueryDSL Class.
so you should run QueryDSL Annotation Processor

maven compile process conatain QueryDSL annotation processor.

type the follow code on your project root.

```html
mvn clean && mvn compile
```